# Add dynamic variable to array name?

Tags: jquery, arrays, syntax

I have three arrays in my script, and I want to push value into one of them, the name of an array is determined of another variable value.

For example: variable value is "3" and I want to push "hello" into wals"3" array.

```js
var wals1 = [];
var wals2 = [];
var wals3 = [];

var res = 3;

wals + res.push("hello");


console.log(wals3);
```

Comment: `window["wals" + res].push("hello")`

Comment: what @mplungjan has mentioned, is correct . But if you ask me, i would recommend using double dimension array to handle your logic.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: wals is not defined
    at window.onload

Comment: You can create a JSON object for that. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON object and then assign the values to the arrays by their dynamic name like this:

```js
var arrayObj = {
 wals1 : [],
  wals2 : [],
  wals3 : []
};
var res = 3;

arrayObj["wals"+res].push("hello");
console.log(arrayObj["wals"+res]);
```

Comment: Ok, i have updated the answer please check now

Comment: Ok works fine, now one more question - how to delete "hello" from wals3?

Comment: Or just s have an array and use wals[0]...wals[2]